# sequelize ERROR: this.lib.createConnection is not a function when using node

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Seeing the following error when trying to run sequelize migration on a mac.
This is built into sequelize, so i have no idea why its not being loaded.

```
npx sequelize-cli db:seed

Sequelize CLI [Node: 10.17.0, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.5.1]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "development".

ERROR: this.lib.createConnection is not a function
```

Answer (score 2):

I was defining the `"dialectModule": "mysql2"` and should not have been.  Removing this line in the config.json fixed the issue.